# Can not set path to a hidden file_Field with Watir

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm using Ruby and Watir to test UI.
I encounted an issue and didn't figure out how to solve it yet.

I have a file field element that has style: 'display: none' and when i try to set a path to a file it returns me a "File Not Found message".
The same time it's easy to ensure that file exist.

The code below illustrates this.

```
0> ff
=> #<Watir::FileField: located: true; {:id=>"fileUpload", :tag_name=>"input", :type=>"file", :index=>0}>

0> path
=> "C:/Users/kpenkin/Documents/watir-tests/specs/test_data.xlsx"

0> File.exist?(path)
=> true

0> Watir.relaxed_locate?
=> false

0> ff.set(path)
=> File not found: C:\Users\kpenkin\Documents\watir-tests\specs\test_data.xlsx

0> ff.wd.send_keys(File.expand_path(path))
=> File not found: C:/Users/kpenkin/Documents/watir-tests/specs/test_data.xlsx

0> ff.exist?
=> true

0> ff.visible?
=> false
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you set relaxed_locate to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug in geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/858). It should work in chrome.
Looks like it is fixed for Firefox 56.

Comment: known bug?  any ETA on a fix?

Comment: Looks like you need to update to Firefox 56 (beta channel)